# IOS 10 Continous permission alerts

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert

I am asking for location, contacts and push notification permission when app launches.These 3 alerts appears continously one after another before user can select it. This issue occurs only in ios 10.

Below version works fine.

In appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[CurrentLocation start]; // Location permission

// Push Notification permission
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
{

UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
 }


// contacts permission

ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (granted)
        {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you specify where and how are you asking for those permissions?

Comment: In app delegate, please see the code. Its working fine in below version.

Comment: From your code it isn't obvious in which AppDelegate method are you calling this snippet. Please updated your code with the view in mind that your code has to provide minimum reproducible example. I guess you are calling it in didFinishLaunch method?

Comment: Also see [How to create minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes. Thats right. Ok I l check.